# SQL equality operators

Tags: sql, operators

I seem to be having problem with sql equality operators. I am getting a syntax error for the following:

```
SELECT CustomerName,City 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName!=null;
```

The error message is as follow:
*Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CustomerName!=null'.*

What exactly is wrong?

Comment: `SELECT CustomerName,City 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName<>null;`

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi: ur query returns nothing.

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim, we can use `!=` in SQL. like `WHERE CustomerName != ''`

Comment: @Sohail Oh, my bad. I never used it! Heh! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Sohail: ya.. it must be `select * from t where customer_name<> ' '` instead [see_here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9991b/3)

Comment: @John: Kindly mark one of below answers as answer.. 
so other may get benifits from your question and marked answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Not all SQL engines support `!=` AFAIK. `<>` is standard.
2. Use `is` to check for `null`

   ```
   WHERE CustomerName is not null;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that:

```
SELECT CustomerName,City 
FROM Customers
WHERE DATALENGTH(CustomerName)>0;
```

OR

```
SELECT CustomerName,City 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName!='';
```

OR

```
SELECT CustomerName,City 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help

```
 select Customername,city from customers where customername is not null;
```